# Is there a common framework which exists across LG, Samsung and Android smart TVs?

Tags: tizen, android-tv, webos, smart-tv

I want to write a program (not an application, but a library) that will run on different Smart TV OS. For example, Samsung Tizen, LG WebOS, Android, Roku, etc.

I somehow see that C++ libraries are supported on all of the above platforms, so creating a C++ library is one solution that I have, but that would involve a big learning curve for my team.

I also know that all the above platforms are Linux kernel based. So, if I can figure out that, say, JRE or Python or any similar framework exists by default in these TVs, I can straight away write a Java or a python program instead of going the C++ way which will surely decrease the learning curve for my team.

The library which I am about to write is supposed to have very good performance and requires huge mathematical calculations and alterations to data, so I am avoiding JS based frameworks. In the worst case, I'll have to fall back to shell scripts, which I surely don't want to do! I'd rather go with C++ in that case.

I need an understanding of the existing architectures of these different TV operating systems for the presence of something like a JRE or Python or anything for that matter.

Comment: I tried to close this as "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" but it has a bounty. This is a question for the vendors of those products

Comment: As far as my research went, I could only find `renative`.